# Press S to skip mount... why did it show up all of the sudden?

Tags: mount, fstab, lubuntu

I already read some advices on other topics, that I should probably just change 'errors=remount-ro' to ignore it, however I am interested why did this message show up in the first place? Did it find some errors? Is it an indication of some other problems?

The only thing I know, I downloaded an .iso from the interwebz on that day, however I did not try to mount it or touch it all, and then I get this message when starting my laptop the next day.

Here's my **fstab**:

```
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=497875d4-0e1e-4ddd-bb92-66a7da7b93c1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=8baa7dbb-c8f0-4779-ac6b-fee56fa4bce6 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sdc /mnt/sdc auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Here's my **blkid**:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="BC64B04B64B00A62" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="A204D87704D85041" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="497875d4-0e1e-4ddd-bb92-66a7da7b93c1" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="8baa7dbb-c8f0-4779-ac6b-fee56fa4bce6" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/zram0: UUID="86a4c525-55f2-45a2-a101-ece5950aa5da" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/zram1: UUID="958e5520-0395-4cfe-b334-159b7872f46c" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/zram2: UUID="b6142f83-db6d-4c70-b115-53908b7b7be1" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/zram3: UUID="287a2ce9-62f0-4203-8364-74783f2ad1bd" TYPE="swap"
```

The main question, is it safe for me to to change 'remount-ro' to 'continue' (or find some other way to ignore the issue)?

Comment: Hmmm.....looks like you already have some type of filesystem problem on one of those. And then system startup flagged it to you.  But there is not enough information presented to really help.

Comment: I'm sorry for not presenting enough information straight away and in that way wasting your time. Won't happen again. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting out UUID=8baa... and /dev/sdc... lines helped, since it was an earlier connected phone that was no longer connected.